# How to use EF code first models to use relationships in order to generate data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have two domain models in my project: Category and Sub-category. This is my one to many relationship and how I created it:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public List<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am not sure how to add a Sub-Category to a Category, but I want the association to be kept for each Sub-Categories in a Category. So I tried passing a Category to my CreateSubCategory View

```
public ActionResult CreateSubCategory(int categoryId)
{
    return View(_service.GetCategory(categoryId));
}
```

I came to here in my view and got stumped

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    <h2>SubCategory</h2>

    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CategoryName)</div>

    <div>@*Want to create Sub-category here*@</div>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
}
```

I guess this is a noob question but I cannot figure out what to do here.
So is there any advice on how to do this, or any way of performing this task of adding my Sub-categories to Categories?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add the virtual keyword.

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

//    add constructor here for category, and set SubCatogories to new HashSet();

```
public class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }// add this:)

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

now there are two ways to add a subcategory;
either get an instance of a Category and then add an instance of SubCategory to its SubCategories collection, or  create a new SubCategory and set its fields including the CategoryId and then add it to its corresponding DbSet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a `SubCategory`, you should be passing a `SubCategory` (or `SubCategoryViewModel`) object as the model to your View.

You can create a new instance of the `SubCategory` in your `CreateSubCategory()` method and assign the `CategoryId` to the new object (as [hazimdikenli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125032/hazimdikenli) pointed out). Be sure to store the Id using `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CategoryId)` so that it's persisted for the returning Post method.

```
public ActionResult CreateSubCategory(int categoryId)
{
    SubCategory model = new SubCategory();
    model.CategoryId = categoryId;
    return View(model);
}
```

When the object is posted back, that is the point where you commit to the database, saving the new object and creating the association with the parent `Category` object (via the Id reference).

If you want to pass the CategoryName, you should probably create a view model with a CategoryName string property (this would of course need to be populated in the `CreateSubCategory()` method)

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to use a single domain model, especially if subcategories can have their own subcategories:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Then configure the relationship in the OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
        .HasMany(x => x.ChildCategories)
        .WithOptional(x => x.ParentCategory);

}
```

To create a new subcategory simply create a new Category and set its ParentCategory before sending the subcategory to your view.